# C++ What is the % operator doing here?

Tags: c++, operators

I recently encountered code similar to this:

```
std::string myString = "test";
boost::format fmt("%s");

fmt % myString;
```

What is the (second) % operator doing here?

EDIT:

I understand the end result, but I could not find a definition of how the % operator can be used like this.

Can someone provide an example that explains what exactly the meaning of the % operator is here?

Comment: performs the actual substitution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: Is the operator overridden by std::string, or by the type of boost::format?

Comment: It's the syntax. `%` is overloaded. It does nothing with modulos and other things.

Comment: Ok, I understand what operator overloading is. I understand that % is normally used for modulus. Does anybody know whether % is being overriden by std::string here or by the type of boost::format?

Comment: It looks similar to the way Python (at least Python 2) uses `%` for the equivalent of `sprintf`, [documented here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). I presume the `%` symbol was chosen as a mnemonic because of that character's use in format strings.

Comment: @mclaassen: `boost::format` overrode the `%` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand the end result, but I could not find a definition of how the % operator can be used like this.

`operator %` can be overloaded. [Boost.Format does exactly that for its `basic_format` class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/format/format_class.hpp):

```
template<class T>  
basic_format&   operator%(const T& x)
    { return io::detail::feed<CharT, Tr, Alloc, const T&>(*this,x); }
```

This member function gets invoked whenever you use the code `fmt % value` where `fmt` is of type `boost::basic_format<Ch>`.

Answer (score 1):

`%` is an overloaded operator.  [Click here.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/format/)